# Getting the absolute url from flask url_for

Tags: python, nginx, flask

this is my current scenario.
i have docker that runs nginx to reverse proxy the request calls to the backend rest api's(implemented using flask module).
and from my docker host machine i mapped 8080 to port 80 of docker, As nginx is running on port 80 of docker.

this is a snippet in nginx.conf which is a call to login api

```
 location /login {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }
```

this is the login api.
so if already logged in. i am  redirecting to ipadd:8080/ or else keep in login page itself.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'], strict_slashes=False)
def index():
   render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET'], strict_slashes=False)
def login():
    """Render the login Page"""
    if check_for_session_util():
       return redirect(url_for("index"),_external=True)
    else:
      return render_template('login.html')
```

but when i hit the url "ipadd:8080/login" it redirecting to "ipadd/" instead of "ipadd:8080/"

Comment: if you expose you api via nginx on port 80 then why are you hitting `ipadd:8080/login` instead you should use `ipadd/login`.

Comment: because i am running nginx in docker. so from client first i will hit the machine that host docker by <ipaddress:8080> that request gets redirected to 80 .

Comment: Any suggestions what needs to be done

Comment: Did you solve this meanwhile?